# Excel Data Validation: for efficiency, type short code but display full/long description

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel Data Validation: for efficiency, type short code but display full/long description

Hello everyone!

I can create a list data validation rule that will display a dropdown menu. It works well but I would like to be more efficient. The issue is that many of my options are similar and you do not get the autocomplete until you've already typed 6 or 7 letters. instead I would like to be able to type a short code and it auto completes the full text. For example, I have a list of possible errors, imagine there are close to 100 options. Many are similar like having 10 options for just for incorrect fields: Incorrect First Name, Incorrect Last Name, Incorrect Birthdate, Incorrect Phone Number etc. I would like to type in a short code of my choosing: IFN for Incorrect First Name and so on.

I have experimented by adding the short code to my list at the beginning, but this creates another issue. Say I do not remember exactly the full name of the error but I do remember that its part of the "incorrect" family, I simply start typing "inco", then when I use the dropdown arrow, the first item starting with "inco" is already highlighted. This is useful because otherwise you would have to scroll down the list and when you have 100 options, it can really slow you down. I could try to keep the short codes at the beginning and just type "I" and it would help scroll down closer to the area I will need, but its not ideal since I could have other error "families" starting with "I" (insufficient, increase etc.)

Any ideas?
I would prefer not to use vba if posible as there are times when it wont be compatible like using from web etc because I share many of my workbooks (co-authoring).

Comment: You would need VBA for this. Look into [Worksheet.Change event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cybernetic.nomad! I should have added that I avoid using vba. I apologize, completly forgot to add that to my OP